# suppressing "incompatible pointer types sending 'subclassA' to parameter of type 'subclassB' " clang

Tags: ios, xcode, clang

Xcode raising "incompatible pointer types sending 'subclassA' to parameter of type 'subclassB' " warning. Compiling with clang.

In the case where the warning is raised, I use a

```
[subclassA isKindOfClass: [subclassB class]] ...
```

to ensure compatible pointer use. I'd like something like:

```
    #pragma clang diagnostic push
    #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
    // warning-raising code
    #pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

but for the appropriate warning raised. I.e. Whats the clang flag to ignore the specified diagnostic?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Diggin' up the dirt: the warning you want to silence is `"-Wincompatible-pointer-types"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you right, you're saying something like

```
if ([subclassA isKindOfClass:[subclassB class]]) {
    [foo someMethodThatWantsSubclassB:subclassA];
}
```

The fix here is to cast `subclassA` after the successful type assertion. Your case is a bit odd in that you're dynamically determining the type of `subclassB` instead of testing for a static type, but in the method `-someMethodThatWantsSubclassB:` you definitely know the type involved, so you'd write something like

```
if ([subclassA isKindOfClass:[subclassB class]]) {
    [foo someMethodThatWantsSubclassB:(BClass)subclassA];
}
```

If you have some really weird setup where you don't actually know the static type of `subclassB` (although I can't imagine the situation here) you could simply cast to `(id)` instead to get rid of the warning:

```
if ([subclassA isKindOfClass:[subclassB class]]) {
    [foo someMethodThatWantsSubclassB:(id)subclassA];
}
```

Comment: Ya its a pretty odd setup - result poor planning on my part. Casting to (id) resolves issue.. silly me. Never had to do that before! Thanks for reading/responding! Much appreciated!

Comment: @Z.O.: I'm curious as to the setup. Even if you don't know the class of `subclassB` at compile-time, you should know the type expected by `-someMethodThatWantsSubclassB:`.